# Вызвать метод формы из другого класса

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу обновить текст в лейбле из другого класса, но не знаю как это сделать.

Запускаю поток в соседнем классе:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(delegate() { Auth.CheckAuth(); });
    thread.Start();
}
```

Сам класс

```
class Auth
{
    public static void CheckAuth()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //тут нужно обновлять информацию в форме
            Form1.label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(delegate() { Form1.label1.Text = "INFO"; }));
            Thread.Sleep(7000);
        }
    }
}
```

Пытался делегатами, но тщетно.

Если через методы - тоже не пойму, что ему нужно.

```
public void update_Label1(string text)
{
    label1.Text = text;
}
```

И

```
Form1.update_Label1("INFO");
```

И вызываю в том же месте в классе. Ругается на статику, но если прописать, то всплывает еще порядка 50 ошибок.

Помогите сделать так, чтобы можно было без проблем осуществить задуманное?

Comment: так ошибку напиши которая появляется

Comment: Что означает «без проблем»? Напишите правильно, и проблем не будет.

Comment: `Form1.update_Label1` очевидно неверно. Вы знаете различие между статическим и нестатическим методом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что *Form1* это не объект, а класс. Поэтому из него можно брать только статические методы, так как label - обычное поле и получаете ошибку.

Вместо это нужно использовать экземпляр класса.

Например:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(delegate() { Auth.CheckAuth(this); });
```

в методе

```
public static void CheckAuth(Form1 form)
```

и внутри примерно

```
form.label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(delegate() { form.label1.Text = "INFO"; }));
```

Comment: Благодарю от души, все работает :-)

Comment: Да, только в этом случае лейбл нужно публичным делать вроде? Иначе ругается на отсутствие доступа.

Comment: @CiJey, возможно, можно и функцию публичную использовать. Главное не путать - объект формы и класс формы

Comment: А чем вообще плохо делать объекты форму публичными? Не зря же они все по умолчанию приватны? Наверное глупый вопрос, но что поделать, интересно же.

Comment: @CiJey, по большому счету ничем :-) просто в ООП подходе принято скрывать внутренности класса и оставать только публичное апи, чтобы тем кто пользуется этим классом, было все равно как он работает - он просто вызвал метод - а у ж каким образом этот метод внутри текст обновил никому не интересно :-)